# IntelliSense: identifier "[blank]" is undefined for each of the variables used in my function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am using Visual Studio. When I try to compile my code, I get an error saying  21  "IntelliSense: identifier "[blank]" is undefined" for each of the variables used in the "hexISOS" function. I have defined these variables later on in the code and was wondering if anybody could tell me what is wrong.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int hexISOS(double AX, AY, BX, BY, CX, CY, DX, DY)
{
    long double sol1, sol2;
    bool ans;

    sol1 = sqrt(pow((AX - CX), 2) + pow((AY - CY), 2));
    sol2 = sqrt(pow((BX - DX), 2) + pow((BY - DY), 2));

    if(sol1 == sol2)
    {
    ans = true;
    }

    else
    {
    ans = false;
    }

    cout << "\nThe distance between A and C is " << sol1 << endl;
    cout << "The distance between B and D is " << sol1 << endl;
    cout << "\nIsosceles = " << ans;

    return 0;
}

int main()
    {
    double AX, AY, BX, BY, CX, CY, DX, DY;

    cout << "AX: ";
    cin >> AX;

    cout << "\nAY: ";
    cin >> AY;

    cout << "\nBX: ";
    cin >> BX;

    cout << "\nBY: ";
    cin >> BY;

    cout << "\nCX: ";
    cin >> CX;

    cout << "\nCY: ";
    cin >> CY;

    cout << "\nDX: ";
    cin >> DX;

    cout << "\nDY: ";
    cin >> DY;

    hexISOS(AX, AY, BX, BY, CX, CY, DX, DY);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That thing where you can use a data type once and then a bunch of variable names - as in the first line of your main function - I don't think you can do that in the parameter list of a function.  Try doing this and see if that helps:

```
int hexISOS(double AX, double AY, double BX, double BY, double CX, double CY, double DX,
        double DY)
```

Edit: Another thing I don't think is legal is this:

```
long double sol1, sol2;
```

You'll probably need to change it to either something like this:

```
long sol1;
double sol2;
```

or something like this:

```
double sol1, sol2;
```